# Which grows faster, $n 2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ or $n^{4/3}$?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Which one grow faster $n 2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$   or  $n^{4/3}$? The log base is 2. My mind tells me first one is grow faster because we have $n$ at the exponential position even though it comes with $\log$ and $\sqrt{.}$. But when I test a large case on computer, computer tells me the second one is larger. Any suggestions?

Comment: Logarithm both expressions. That might make it easier.

Comment: good suggestion. Thanks

Comment: It's also smart to divide both by $n$, so that you're comparing $2^{\sqrt{\log n}}$ with $n^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestions in the comments to heart, let's divide by $n$ and the the logarithm (base $2$), giving:

$$\sqrt{\log n } \quad \wedge \quad \frac{1}{3}\log n,$$

so the second expression will clearly grow faster. It overtakes the first when 
$$\sqrt{\log n }=\frac{1}{3}\log n \implies n=2^9,$$

where we have thrown away the solution $n=1$, as it clearly doesn't fit our criterion.

Comment: Wait, you mean second one grow faster when we have a great n, right?

Comment: If we subtract both sides by log n. We have square root of (log n) but we have (1/3) log n.

Comment: I assume (1/3) is not a big deal. So we have a (square root of log n) on left and (log n) on right, isn't it?

Comment: @Nick Yes, sorry, my mistake, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\log_n$ on both sides gives
$$1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_2 n}}$$
for the first one and
$$4/3$$
for the second one.
So once $n > 2^9$, the second expression is larger.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. you are right

Comment: That'd do it. Not sure how I missed that, thanks.